# Derivative of $X^{-1}AX^{-1}$ w.r.t. X

Tags: calculus, matrices, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I want to calculate the derivative of $X^{-1}AX^{-1}$ w.r.t. X in a simple form

Let
\begin{align}
AX^{-1}&=Y\\
X^{-1}A&=Z\\
dX^{-1} &= -X^{-1}dXX^{-1}\\
\text{vec}(dX^{-1}) &= -(X^{-T} \otimes X^{-1})\text{vec}(dX),
\end{align}
were $\text{vec}$ is the vectorization operator.

We have
\begin{align}
F &= X^{-1}AX^{-1}\\
\implies dF & = d(X^{-1})AX^{-1} + X^{-1}Ad(X^{-1})\\
\implies dF & = d(X^{-1})Y + Zd(X^{-1})\\
\implies \text{vec}(dF) & = (Y^T \otimes I)\text{vec}(dX^{-1}) + (I \otimes Z) \text{vec} (dX^{-1})\\
\implies \text{vec}(dF) & = (Y^T \otimes I)\text{vec}(dX^{-1}) + (I \otimes Z) \text{vec}(dX^{-1})\\
& = -[(Y^T \otimes I) + (I \otimes Z)](X^{-T} \otimes X^{-1}) \text{vec}(dX)\\
& = -[((AX^{-1})^T \otimes I) + (I \otimes X^{-1}A)](X^{-T} \otimes X^{-1}) \text{vec}(dX)\\
\end{align}
Can we obtain a simple formula of this result?
Thank you.

Comment: The derivative at $X$ is the linear map $$B \mapsto -X^{-1} B X^{-1} A X^{-1} - X^{-1} A X^{-1} B X^{-1}$$ for each matrix $B$.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy, vec is the vectorization operator.

Comment: @WimC, what is B?

Comment: Why use vectorization and tensor product?\begin{align*}d(X^{-1}AX^{-1})&=d(X^{-1})AX^{-1}+X^{-1}A\,d(X^{-1})\\&=-X^{-1}dXX^{-1}A X^{-1}—X^{-1}AX^{-1}\,dXX^{-1}\end{align*}

Comment: $B$ is essentially $dA$

Comment: How about this 
$$\large{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\X{X^{-1}} \def\XT{X^{-T}}
df = -(F^T\otimes\X \;+\; \XT\otimes F)\:dx \\
}$$

Comment: @greg, elegant as expected